# How can I store the result of an XQuery in the database?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have the following .xquery file.

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
(: the output will be presented as html :)
declare option exist:serialize "method=html media-type=text/html indent=yes";

let $something:=""

return
   <html>
      <head>Stackoverflow rocks!</head>
      <body>
         <div>
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

How can I bind the returned HTML page to `$variable` in order to store it using this expression:

```
let $store:=xmldb:store('/db/apps/mycollection','page.html',$variable)
return
    $store
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like the following (not tested)?

```
xquery version "3.0";  
declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
(: the output will be presented as html :)
declare option exist:serialize "method=html media-type=text/html indent=yes";

let $doc := 
    <html>
      <head>Stackoverflow rocks!</head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h>
        </div>
      </body>
     </html>,

    $store := xmldb:store('/db/apps/mycollection',
                          'page.html',
                          $doc)
return if ($store eq '') then
    'Sorry, attempted to store document but failed.'
else
    concat('Stored document at ', $store)
```

Comment: The above will store the document as 'application/xml' and eXist will add it to it's DOM and index it, which is most likely what is wanted. However if you wanted to store it in eXist as just html (text) without eXist really doing anything special you could use 'xmldb:store('/db/apps/mycollection',
                          'page.html',
                          $doc, 'text/html')

Comment: It works just fine. Thank you @C. M. Sperberg-McQueen. I've did something like this for a xml file in the past, but this "method" didn't crossed my mind. Silly me.